# How do you force the type of data in a cv::Mat to be float upon creation?

Tags: c++, opencv

When iterating through a cv::Mat to output all of its values, you could do the following:

```
for (int r = 0; r < t.rows; r++)
{
    for (int c = 0; c < t.cols; c++)
    {
        std::cout << t.at<float>(r,c) << ", ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;
}
```

However, if the information stored in that array is not of type float, this will crash.  How do you enforce the type of this matrix?

Comment: I don't know OpenCV but in general get the [typeid](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fthe_typeid_operator.htm) of elements and if it isn't float, throw exception.

Comment: now when i read the question again, i wonder... do you know that you can put any type instead of float in the t.at<float>(r,c) call? if you know that the matrix is a matrix of ints you can do t.at<int>(r,c) and it will work great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

for 2 Mats `nonFloatMat` and `floatMat` when the first is the source matrix and the last is the destination matrix do

```
nonFloatMat.convertTo(floatMat, CV_32F); //if its a color image use CV_32FC3, or 
                                         // CV_32FC4 if its RGBA
```

[convertTo](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/basic_structures.html#index-1012)'s reference can be found [here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/basic_structures.html#index-1012).

**Edit:**

and by the way, the code will work if you'll change the float to the correct concrete type of the matrix ie if the mat is a `CV_8U` you can do `t.at<char>(r,c)` etc.

Comment: Can it be enforced from the start?  I have it defined as cv::Mat t;  t = some_other_matrix(cv::Range(some range), cv::Range(another range));

Comment: nothing prevents you from doing (some_other_matrix(cv::Range(some range), cv::Range(another range)).convertTo(floatMat, CV_32F);, there is no additional parameter for operator() to define type conversion.

Answer (score 3):

While Boaz correctly answers your questions, converting your matrix adds a new problem Your function will allocate some new memory, will convert data, and then will perform calculations.

This adds a significant overhead for your function. The solution is to make a branch for every data type you suppose to support. This is the way OpenCV handles multiple data types (of course, it's a bit smarter than if-else)

```
if(mat.type()==CV_32FC1)
{
}
else if(mat.type()==CV_32FC3)
{
}
else if(mat.type()==CV_8UC3)
{
}
...
```

**another solution**, if your only aim is to print the matrix is

```
cout << myMat << endl;
```

Isn't it great?

Comment: Thanks and I agree about the overhead.  Problem is, for some reason the image's don't always come in at the same format.  Some appear to be unsigned char, some float, some signed char, etc.  To compare the data, I need them to be the same.  Pretty cool solution on printing too, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with the template wrapper class called [Mat_](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=mat_#Mat_).

So, to "force" the type of the matrix to `float` you could do the following:

```
Mat_<float> A(100, 100);
```

Also, another way to ensure a matrix is of a certain type (this is done quite a bit in the OpenCV source) is to use an assertion.

Like this:

```
void functionOnlyUsesFloatMats(const Mat& src)
{
    CV_Assert( src.type() == CV_32FC1 );

    // now you can be assured that only single-channel float matrices reach this code...
}
```

Or, you could check the type before proceeding, and convert if needed:

```
Mat floatMat;
if(src.type() != CV_32FC1)
{
    src.convertTo(floatMat, CV_32F);
}
else
{
    floatMat = src;
}

// proceed with float calculations...
```

Comment: Of course using `_Mat<float>` doesn't force anything. It just casts (not converts) the matrix into a float matrix, which will get you into trouble as soon as the matrix is not of type `CV_32FC1`.